# How to convert Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP) with indefinite constraints into Second Order Cone Program (SOCP)?

Tags: convex-optimization, qcqp, second-order-cone-programming

In their [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/socp.pdf), "Applications of Second Order Cone Programming," Boyd, Vandenberghe et al introduce the following procedure to convert a quadratic constraint into a second order cone constraint.

For $P_i$ positive semidefinite the constraint,

\begin{equation}
x^TP_ix + 2q_i^Tx+r_i\le0
\end{equation}

may be transformed to

\begin{equation}
||P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i||\le(q_i^TP^{-1}q_i-r_i)^{.5}
\end{equation}

In the paper the following assertion is made

> We will assume for simplicity that the matrices are positive definite, although the problem can be reduced to an SOCP in general.

So, my question: **How is this transformation extended to support a constraint with indefinite $P_i$?**

For the PSD case,

\begin{equation}
||P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i||^2 = (P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i)^T(P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i)
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
x^T(P_i^{.5})^TP_i^{.5}x+2(P_i^.5)^TP_i^{-.5}q_i^Tx+q_i^T(P_i^{-.5})^TP_i^{-.5}q_i
\end{equation}

which simplifies to

\begin{equation}
x^TP_ix+2q_i^Tx+q_i^TP^{-1}q_i
\end{equation}

However, I can't figure out how to extend this to an  indefinite matrix where the matrix square root would have complex components...

In the case of an indefinite $P_i$, I think the norm on the right hand side would now be the square root of a vector times its complex conjugate transpose, something like,

\begin{equation}
   ||P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i|| = \sqrt{(P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i)^*(P_i^{.5}x+P_i^{-.5}q_i)}
\end{equation}

but I am struggling to figure out the formulation to understand how this would work. It seems like instead of the matrix square root, I need a formulation where

\begin{equation}
P_i  = A^*A
\end{equation}

for some square matrix $A$, but I have been unable to find such a decomposition and have seen several places that a matrix times it's conjugate transpose will be positive semidefinite (in which case there wouldn't be a way to construct an indefinite matrix from such a decomposition).

Apologies for any confusion in this explanation, but thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What you are looking for is a Cholesky decomposition, and maybe this will help https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#convex-quadratic-sets

Comment: On second thought, maybe I misunderstood the question. If you are asking how to transform a quadratic constraint with arbitrary P to a second-order cone, the answer is it is impossible, because such a constraint is not convex in the first place. The "... in general" in the paper refers only to definite vs. semidefinite.

Comment: ok thank you very much for clarifying